# UIView animation with duration much faster than specified

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

I am using a UIView animation to set up a "loading screen" and then make the loading screen disappear once a NSURLSessionDataTask has completed. The code below ideally would draw a rectangle subview on a monocolor background and then rotate and translate that rectangular subview until the DataTask executes its completion block:

```
void getData()
{
    ....
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [sharedSessionMainQueue dataTaskWithRequest:req 
                                    completionHandler: ^(NSData *data,
                                    NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){

         NSMutableArray *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                      options:0
                                                                        error:nil];

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

             ...
             [UIView animateWithDuration:10 animations:^{
                 [_ballView removeFromSuperview];
                 [_tempview removeFromSuperview];
             }];

         }];

        [self.view addSubview:_tempview];
        _ballView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_width/2 - 10, _height*.9, 10.0f, 80.0f)];
        _ballView.center = CGPointMake(_width*.5, _height*.3);
        _ballView.backgroundColor = BACKGROUND_COLOR; //[UIColor orangeColor];
        [self.view addSubview: _ballView];

        CGFloat angleToRotate = 20*M_PI;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
            [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:100];
            CGRect f = _ballView.frame;
            f.origin.y = _height*.1;
            _ballView.frame = f;
            _ballView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleToRotate);

        } completion:nil];

        [dataTask resume];
    }

}
```

But I have two problems. First the animation completes very fast - far less than a second - no matter what duration I specify in either of the animation blocks. Second, the block translates but it doesn't rotate.

Any ideas on what's going on? Does something funky happen with UIView animation inside completion blocks?

Thank you!

Comment: can you please fix the code formatting, I can't see where the dispatch_async block is intended to close

Comment: @Lyndsey thanks for formatting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First block animation (with removeFromSuperview calls) will complete almost immediately, because removeFromSuperview isn't animatable. You should use something some like

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10 animations:^{
    _ballView.alpha = 0;
    _tempview.alpha = 0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [_ballView removeFromSuperview];
    [_tempview removeFromSuperview];
}];
```

The problem in the second block, is that you need to convert degrees to radians, but anyway, it doesn't work, because it will rotate from same start angle. You need to use NSTimer, or much easier and better - CAAnimation:

```
CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
CGFloat duration = 2, repeat = 50;
rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0 * duration ];
rotationAnimation.duration = duration;
rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
rotationAnimation.repeatCount = repeat;

[view.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
```

Comment: thank you so much. This worked like a charm! I had forgotten that alpha's are on the list of not so many things that are animateable. I was using radians, so I don't think that's why my rotation wasn't working, but in any case this is great. Thanks again!